# How to assign values of a matrix to variables in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I have created a `50 x 1` matrix in ubuntu as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A matrix
num_rows=1
num_columns=50

for ((n=0;n<=(($num_columns-1));n++)) do
for ((i=1;i<=num_rows;i++)) do
    matrix[$i,$j]=net$(($n+1))
    #echo "${matrix[$i,$j]}" >> temp
done
done
```

Now I want to assign each element of the 50 x 1 matrix to a variable (say 'q'); for instance q1=net1, q2=net2,...q50=net50. Does anyone know how to achieve this in linux? Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want variables that are named according to the lower-case version of the values in the matrix variable, and to be assigned the corresponding upper-case version as a value?

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually trying to do.  Are you trying to convert the array to flat assignments or something else?  Not sure what would be the point of defining a variable that contains its name.

Comment: No I had used those alphabets as example to convey my question. I have edited the question now. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: If you show us the loop you use to produce your array output, you'll be half-way done.  All that would be lacking is a counter and possibly using `declare` to assign your variables.

Comment: I have added my code in the question!

Comment: Bash is not a good language for anything more complex than strings and lists of strings. Use a “real” programming language like Python, R, …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, I'm creating a list of variables prefixed with `q` followed by a sequential number (c) which is then assigned your array variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A matrix
num_rows=1
num_columns=50

c=1

for ((n=0;n<=(($num_columns-1));n++)) do
    for ((i=1;i<=num_rows;i++)) do
        matrix[$i,$j]=net$(($n+1))
        declare "q$c=${matrix[$i,$j]}"
        ((c++))
    done
done
```

To output them, you can use something like:

```
for ((i=1;i<(($num_columns-1));i++)) do
    var=q$i
    echo "${!var}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! How do I print the contents of the new matrix "q$c"?

Comment: I just updated my answer to show you a way to do it, but that seems to me like you're getting rid of an array but still want to deal with the result as an array which is counter productive.

Comment: Well I don't want my result in the form of an array; I just wanted to be sure that the solution you proposed works :)